# Using PynamoDB to put an item with new attributes

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I have existing DynamoDB tables created through an infrastructure-as-code implementation.

I used TableConnection to connect to the existing table and run the lower level command `put_item`.

My table is defined with a hash key (`userId`) and sort key (`transactionId`).

I want to put an item with additional attributes (`timestamp`, `symbol`, `quantity`).

I have not defined these additional attributes.

When I run the following command:

```
table = TableConnection('ExistingTable')
table.put_item(user_id, transaction_id, attributes={...})
```

I receive the following error:

`ValueError: No attribute timestamp in ['userId', 'transactionId']`

How do I put an item without defining the attributes previously?

Comment: This shouldn’t be the case - do you have some sample code that we can replicate on a sample table? Its not clear exactly how you’re defining your attributes for updating. And what version of PynamoDB?

Comment: I define my table in Serverless Stack which is an IaC tool. It only allows definition of hash and sort keys - no additional attributes. I am NOT using PynamoDB's Model class (hence my other question you answered). I agree that this should be possible given TableConnection has no concept of a Python model. I am using PynamoDB 5.2.1.

Comment: I understand, of course. This isn’t reproducible however, do you mind sharing the exact line that you're using? Are you missing any commas or arguments maybe by accident?